# Creating non-restful rails pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I have just moved from using php mvc frameworks to rails and have been going through the guides and devouring railscasts.

It seems that everything is based around restful resources and creating functionality around these parts is intuitive.

The non-restful/non-model-based parts are slightly less intuitive or at least seem to be less covered by documentation.

There's 3 types of users in my web app. When a user logs in then I want them to be displayed a dashboard page with some basic summary information depending on which type of user they are.

Whats the best way to represent this? Do I just create a new Action Controller called Dashboard to represent this non-model-based functionality and then create the methods I need like show or is there a better strategy?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could create a new Dashboard controller.

If it will likely only be the show action, you could just add a new dashboard method to your users controller and the route `match "/users/:id/dashboard" => "users#dashboard"`.

Comment: make that `match "/users/:id/dashboard" => "users#dashboard", :as => :dashboard` and you get a `dashboard_url` url helper for free!

Answer (score 2):

Rails makes your life really easy if you can think about your app restfully. Whenever you need to build new functionality, think about what the user is doing. Focus on the "noun" .

- Are you showing a list of things, possibly filtered or sorted? **:index**
- Are you showing a thing that is one of many? Or is there only one? **:show**
- Does the user need to build a new thing? This doesn't always mean saving to a database. Display it in **:new** and POST the result to **:create**
- Is the user modifying a thing? PUT to **:update**. Is there a view of the thing or a page before it is modified? Use **:edit**
- Is something being removed? **:delete**

If it confuses you, don't get wrapped up in the difference between **:index** and **:show**. Put your functionality in **:index** to start, and you'll learn if you need to move it to **:show**.

Also learn about the differences between a normal RESTful resource and a singular resource - sometimes (like in the case of your Dashboard) it might make more sense to use `resource :dashboard` and then put the functionality in the `:show` action.

Get familiar with http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html, and remember to consider the non-model "things" even though they are not models.

**IN YOUR CASE:** You have three types of users, and a dashboard. You could represent the User and their Role as models, and store that information in the session (user_id). Then when the user visits `/dashboard`, they see their custom view (rendered in `dashboard#show`) based on the User and Role objects.